# IBM i OS/400 QSH - shell script

Tags: shell, startup, tivoli

I've got a startup/stop script provided for Tivoli Workload Scheduler in which it will start/stp[ the TWS services in IBM i.

```
    # CHECK ROOT USER
    WHO=`id | cut -f1 -d" "`
    if [ "$WHO" = "uid=0(root)" ]
    then
    su TWSSVC -c "/etc/rc.d/init.d/tebctl-tws_cpa_agent_TWSSVC stop"
    exit $?
    fi

    /etc/rc.d/init.d/tebctl-tws_cpa_agent_TWSSVC stop
    exit $?
```

Problem with this is that, in OS/400 the equivalent of root is QSECOFR, so I've amended the line

```
 if [ "$WHO" = "uid=0(root)" ]
```

to

```
 if [ "$WHO" = "uid=0(QSECOFR)" ]
```

then i got an error on the following line:

```
 su TWSSVC -c "/etc/rc.d/init.d/tebctl-tws_cpa_agent_TWSSVC stop"

 /TWSSVC/TWS/ShutDownLwa: 001-0019 Error found searching for command su. No such path or directory.
```

How do I change to script such that, when it is QSECOFR, it will su into TWSSVC and trigger the start/stop script? I'm not very familiar with OS400. I'm triggering this script in qsh environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following;

```
sudo TWSSVC -c "/etc/rc.d/init.d/tebctl-tws_cpa_agent_TWSSVC stop"
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Hi nu1silva,       `/TWSSVC/TWS/ShutDownLwa: 001-0019 Error found searching for command sudo. No such path or directory.`

Comment: what environment are you on? (Ubuntu/CentOS/RHEL)?

does su or sudo in terminal work properly?

Comment: Hi nu1silva, this is a IBM i machine running on OS/400, i ran the commands in Qshell.

Comment: sorry, my bad didn't read the subject properly. anyway this is totally different from Unix/Linux where you use su/sudo. you might have to switch to a user who has permission. check this out [QSYGETPH](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2FQSYGETPH.htm) and this also [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/413451/runas-or-sudo-equivalent-on-as400-ibm-iseries). hope it helps